# Своё синтетическое событие React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouse-event

Доброго времени суток, начал изучать React js, столкнулся с вопросом - Можно ли создать своё синтетическое событие в React?

пересмотрел события связанные с мышью:
onClick onContextMenu onDoubleClick onDrag onDragEnd onDragEnter onDragExit
onDragLeave onDragOver onDragStart onDrop onMouseDown onMouseEnter onMouseLeave onMouseMove onMouseOut onMouseOver onMouseUp
Нужного не нашел.

Возникла необходимость создать событие, которое при клике  **на любом элементе(грубо говоря теге "body", кроме того, на котором висит событие, происходила реакция**.

Буду признателен за совет!

Событие хочу повесить на элемент input в компоненте task.

Впринципе как это сделать на jquery/native я понимаю, но вот в React...

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser.js"></script>
<style>
    .editor
    {
        width: 30%;
        background: aqua;
        height: 250px;
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        border: dashed 3px yellow;
    }

    .task
    {
        width: 150px;
        min-height:50px;
        background:green;
        color:aqua;
        border: dashed 3px yellow;
    }

</style>
```

```
<div id='project'></div>

<script type="text/babel">
    var Task = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        text: 'default text',
        sost: 1 
    };
},
txtChange:function()
{
    this.setState({ sost: 0 });
},
 txtChange2:function()
{
    this.setState({ sost: 1 });
},

        render: function()
        {
            return( 
                <div className="task">

                {  ((this.state.sost)==1) && <span onClick={this.txtChange}>{this.state.text}</span> }
                {  ((this.state.sost)==0) && <input onMouseOut={this.txtChange2} value={this.state.text} />  }
                    <button className="delete" onClick="">X</button>
                </div>
                );
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
         <div><Task />   </div>,
        document.getElementById('project')
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вопрос не до конца ясен, но если вы повесите onClick на самый верхний компонент (грубо говоря <App />), то клик на любом элементе станет триггером для вашего обработчика. target и currentTarget будут содержать элемент, вызвавший событие и элемент, на котором событие висит

Comment: e.preventDefault() не позволит событию подниматься выше по конмпонентам приложения

Comment: кстати, createClass больше не поддерживается

Comment: Ну как, получилось?